# express-session not working in safari and IOS

Tags: ios, node.js, express, safari, express-session

I am working on an express server, that used as an API for 3 web apps (admin, clients, and miniAdmin).

The project is in staging for testing before production, but the problem is that the cookies not saving on safari on macs, and all the browsers on IOS and IpadOS.

```
app.use(session({
        name: `sid-${nconf.get('ServerConfig:projectName')}`, // The name of the session ID cookie
        cookie: {
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'localhost', // If true, requires HTTPS
            httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'localhost',
            sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'localhost' ? 'none' : 'strict'
        },
        secret: ****, // Signs the cookie - changing this will invalidate all existing cookies.
        resave: false, // Forces the session to be saved back to the session store no matter what - We don't want this unless the session has changed.  
        saveUninitialized: false, // Sessions will only be created when user logs in when the value is false
        store: MongoStore.create({
            clientPromise: Promise.resolve(mongoose.connection.getClient()),
            autoRemove: 'native', // Removes expired sessions
            stringify: false // Prevents stringification of the session data
        })
    }));
```

Please help.
thanks :)

Comment: I'd suggest logging what your three cookie settings are in the above code to make sure the environment is set properly and those settings are what you expect them to be.  I'm specifically wondering if you're using some combination of those settings that Safari doesn't like.   Also, can you go into the developer screen on Safari and see the cookie in Safari?  The question is whether Safari isn't saving it or Safari isn't sending it back to your host on some future request?

Comment: Also, are you experiencing the issue when sending requests to your server with Javascript from a web page?  Or just with regular web page requests by the browser.  If the former, please show the client-side Javascript code making the request.

Comment: Pretty hard to help you when you aren't responding to questions or suggestions.  Stackoverflow doesn't work very well if you post and disappear.

Comment: Pls am running through this issue too. How did you get it solve?

Comment: I am experiencing the very same issue with IOS. I can see everything is working fine with Android. Its not only Safari but Chrome+IOS as well.